# converting old html form servlets to run on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

My java servlets have been running perfectly out of my html forms for many, many years. Now my long-time ISP has thrown in the towel so I had to get a new ISP. They support my servlets, they say, and I have a private Tomcat 7 installation. I expected to be able to just change the pathing in my html forms and servlet code, recompile, and run. However, that is failing. I don't have any jsp, war files, or xml. Never needed any.

The new ISP has the public_html/ mapped to my_domain/ (no problem) and the webapps/ dir (new to me) to my_domain-webapps/ which is at the same level structurally as my_domain/. There are servlet examples under this my_domain-webapps/ dir but I can't tell what the url is to access them. I've tried appending 8080 to my_domain but that fails too. (http://www.my_domain.com:8080/examples/) I also tried http://www.my_domain-webapps.com:8080/examples/ that also failed.

I access my code on linux with putty using vim. There is no cpanel type admin.

I've searched and searched for an explanation but cannot find one. I have read over the Apache documentation but it doesn't help either. I will keep searching but am hoping someone here can help.

Can anyone tell me how to make my old html form servlets run under Tomcat 7 [[ the url for the -webapps dir ]]? Perhaps point me to documentation describing how to run simple old html form servlets out of Tomcat 7 or give me a brief explanation?

edit:
as requested, here is the info:

The servlet code is not the issue. I'm asking about the url to access the examples provided by tomcat installation.
path to my domain: /path/to/domain/my_domain/
accessed with url:  http://www.my_domain.com/
This directory has an index.html provided by myself and it shows fine in a browser.

path to tomcat 7 examples:  /path/to/domain/my_domain-webapps/examples/
    [[ -webapps/examples/ is literal, remainder is conceptual ]]
This directory has an index.html provided by the tomcat installation. I didn't change it in any way.

trying to access the examples with url:
    http://www.my_domain.com/examples/index.html
tomcat error log says:
    ... File does not exist: /path/to/domain/my_domain/examples

trying to access the examples with url:
    http://www.my_domain-webapps.com/examples/index.html
error page says:
    Server not found

Comment: Please edit your question to contain actual code: what does your servlet look like, what does a typical form look like, and what do you see in the tomcat log? What do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I am the only person in the world who has run into this issue so I will post the answers I've found. Maybe someone will yet also post other pertinent info.

>> how to make my old html form servlets run under Tomcat 7:
    - The answer to this, as near as I can determine at this time, is that I have to become a conformist and use the directory structure dictated by the servlet spec 2.2+ and by my ISP, including the web.xml and war file. That means it is not possible to run my servlets from html forms the way they have been running for many years. A war file is required - not optional.
Now I am aiming to determine the minimalist set of required files and directories required to run servlets from html forms under Tomcat.

>> [what is] the url to access the examples provided by the Tomcat installation (where the path to my domain is /path/to/domain/my_domain/ and the path to the tomcat examples is: /path/to/domain/my_domain-webapps/examples/):
    - The answer to this is that the url is http://www.my_domain/examples/ (as we would expect). The reason it wasn't working for me was that a "context" had to be added to the setup. That coupled with the Apache webserver configuration provide the mapping needed to access web content in the two par-level directory structures.

I got chunks of info from a few different places then determined the answers to my specific questions by experimenting. In particular, my ISP, Tomcat documentation (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) and Marty Hall's info at CoreServlets.com (http://www.coreservlets.com/). CoreServlets was once again invaluable. (I originally learned servlets from him back at the dawn of time. I got stuck in the past - and didn't mind a bit - until it bit me.)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7 has nothing to do with it.

You shouldn't need to change anything at all. Your form should contain relative URLs, relative to the deployment context oath, and your web.xml ditto.

The only questions are for your ISP: what is the hostname and what is the Tomcat port?

Comment: You are not understanding my question or I'm probably not being clear enough. Tomcat is the central point of my question.  --  You say "deployment context oath"  and "your web.xml". I did say in my original question that regarding my old servlets I have no xml. "deployment context oath" is unknown to me. It used to be very simple and straight forward. Now it is complicated and crazed. I guess I'm an old guy, been around the web since the dawn of time and not kept up. Well, I have to change that but need to get off the starting block.       What is the url to access the tomcat 7 examples?

Comment: Don't be silly. How would anybody else know your URL? The context path is the directory under 'webapps' in which your servelts were deployed. Only you know that as well. As long as that's the same as before, all you have to do is adjust the hostname and port. But this time I suggest you write yourself a web.xml and create a proper WAR file so you will never have this problem again.

Comment: Well, that didn't answer my question. I don't need a lecture, I need information. It appears that I need someone who understands how it used to be to explain. You did give me one piece of info though so thanks for that "The context path is the directory under 'webapps' in which your servelts were deployed.".

Comment: Nonsense. I gave you several pieces of information. I told you you didn't have to change anything. I told you Tomcat 7 has nothing to do with it. These are all answers to the question you asked. I *also* told you about the context path, in comments, in answer to another comment, but it's astonishing that you didn't already know that.